# array re/assignment reference changes

Tags: javascript

In javascript arrays are objects therefore passed by reference. So

```
var a = ["a"];
var b = a;
console.log(b);
a[0] = "wtv";
console.log(b);
```

will change b value.

what I don't understand is why

```
var a = ["a"];
var b = a;
console.log(b);
a = ["wtv"];
console.log(b);
```

is not changing b value ? what is the reasoning behind this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the value in memory `a` points to is changed by the assignment `a = ["wtv"];`.

while in the first example you change a part/property of `a`, while the object in memory `a` points to stays the same.

An image to explain it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're `b` is just *copying* a reference to `a`.

So they have copies of the same reference, but they each have their *own* copy of that reference.

```
var a = ["a"];

// b now holds a copy of the reference from a
var b = a;

// when you change a, b is unaffected since it has an independent reference
// a now points to a new location in memory
// a has a new reference, whereas b still has the reference from before
a = ["wtv"];
```

However, since the two variable *do* have the same reference, even though they are copies, you can change data within the object or array itself and have it affect both variables.

Take this for example:

```
// a points to a location in memory
var a = [];

// we give a some value
a["foo"] = 'bar';

// b now has a *copy* of a's location in memory
var b = a;

// since b shares the same location in memory as a, it has the same foo value
console.log(b.foo); // => bar

// we update a's foo value
a["foo"] = 'baz';

// since b still shares the same location in memory as a, 
// it's pointing to the same foo from a, therefore it's also affected
console.log(b.foo); // => baz
```

[**@Hidde**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711129/hidde) has a great image that helps visualize what's going on behind the scenes with where the memory is pointing.

Answer (score 1):

With `a = ["wtv"];` you assign brand new array to variable `a`. It has nothing to do with it's former reference.

Answer (score 1):

An array in JavaScript is also an object and objects are always passed/assigned by reference. Thus both variables have a reference to the same object, thus making a change in one will reflect a change in another as both are pointing to the same value.

Whereas in the later case, you are assigning a new value to the `var a` and this will be stored at different memory location and not on the one on which `b` is stored, it is similar like doing

```
var a = 5;
var b = a;
a = a - 1;
alert(b); // alerts 5
alert(a); // alerts 4
```